# Extract sub string from a variable based on special characters in shell script

Tags: shell, substring

I've a variable where I would like to extract the content surrounded by a special character. In my case the character is `%`.

The value stored in the variable goes this way:

```
"something.. : something.. %Required Value 1% something.. %Required Value 2% : something.. "
```

The response is filled with different special characters and the value is coming from a different script.

From the above response, I want to extract the values surrounded with `%`. The output I'm looking for is

```
Required Value 1
Required Value 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -v RS='%' '(NR+1)%2' <<< "something.. : something.. %Required Value 1% something.. %Required Value 2% : something.. "
Required Value 1
Required Value 2
```

`RS`, the record separator, is set to `%`. The only statement prints all even record number, e.g.  `NR`=2, 4, 6...

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
> export X="something.. : something.. %Required Value 1% something.. %Required Value 2% : something.. "
> perl -e ' BEGIN { $p=$ENV{X}; while($p=~m/(.+?)%(.+?)%(.+)/) { $p=$3; print "$2\n" }} '
Required Value 1
Required Value 2
>
```